# Working practices with Git

Tags: git, github

We're just moving to git from svn. With svn, on our local development machines we've been used to having a local folder structure like:

- Project dir
- Trunk
- Branches
- Branch 1 (sub dir of Branches)

Do developers tend to have a similar working practices with Git? It seems like they all have to be checked out to the folder that has the .git folder, so we could just have Master / Feature branch 1 etc all the same folder. Is that the norm?

thanks in advance 
 dotdev

Answer (score 2):

Branching works very differently in Subversion than in almost every other version control system. Subversion models branches and tags as directories. This causes great problems when trying to merge them. It means branching and tagging in Subversion is not standardized and there's many different philosophies about how to lay out your branches and how to manage your working directory.

Git (and just about every other version control system) models branches as sort of views on the state of the code. ***There can only be one branch checked out in your working directory at a time***. The norm in Git is to have a single repository working directory (a clone of the whole repository) and to switch between branches with `git checkout`.

Git's branches are far faster and easier than Subversion, so long lived branches are generally discouraged. You typically have a branch for development (usually `master`), a branch for production, and then people create and merge short-lived feature branches. Rather than working on `master`, typically people develop in feature branches and only merge with master.

[There are a great number of Git workflows out there](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/). As SVN users you'll probably want to pick one that's conceptually close to the centralized model and, once you're more comfortable, work up from there.